# Get only different month and date from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get only month and year from the table and to create and display it in list I've managed to do it this way:

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT  
                                            MONTHNAME(m_post_date) AS month,
                                            YEAR(m_post_date) AS year)
                                            FROM $table_name  " );    ?>
```

And later display it in loop this way:

```
            <li><?php echo $retrieved_data->year.' '.$retrieved_data->month; ?></li>
```

I just need now not to show dublicated records when both year and month are the same. 
For example when I have

```
2017 May 
2017 May
```

website should show only one item. I've thought about distinct keyword but that doesn't work the way I want.

btw it's in wordpress but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Lookup GROUP BY. Then add a group by and order by clause to your select.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY year, month`

Comment: Performance issues aside, DISTINCT is actually the term you're looking for - although you handle this just as effectively in your output loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(m_post_date) AS month,
       YEAR(m_post_date) AS year
FROM $table_name
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(m_post_date), YEAR(m_post_date);
```